# Cannot find existing Java version from JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, installation

I have installed java successfully

```
[ ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/
[ ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin
```

But while starting my application, I am getting error like :

```
Cannot find existing Java version from JAVA_HOME
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your JAVA_HOME is wrong:

set it to `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/`

Comment: @Kute Is the JDK installed in `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/`? Is there a java in the bin directory?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but have you tried removing last slash 
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07